# .NET Core 2.0 console application does not compile

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I want to configure a **.NET Core 2.0 CONSOLE** application. There is one line that **won't compile** (see my note in the code).

I have checked so many blogs, websites, etc. This seems to be an approved way of configuring a .NET Core application. Am I missing an assembly reference?

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace fbs.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        public static IConfiguration configuration;
        public static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create service collection
            ConfigureServices();

            var dbService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbContext>();
        }

        private static void ConfigureServices()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            configuration = builder.Build();

            var appSettings = new AppSettings();
            var section = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");

            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddOptions();
            // The following statement does NOT compile???
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(section); 
            services.AddSingleton<IDbContext, DbContext>();

            serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }

    public class AppSettings
    {
        public string Database { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IDbContext
    {
        string Database { get; set; }
    }

    public class DbContext : IDbContext
    {
        public string Database { get; set; }

        public DbContext(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            this.Database = appSettings.Value.Database;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
The compiler error says:

```
Error CS1503    Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to 'System.Action<fbs.Console.AppSettings'.
```

In order to replicate the problem, just create a new .NET Core 2.0 console application, copy&paste my code and try to compile.

Comment: Please update your question to give us more information: title does not describe the problem, provide error messages, insert some links to blogs and websites you visited.

Comment: @FIL: You are right. Sorry about that. Anyways, the problem is solved (see my edit). Thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score 2):

**Solved:** 
Indeed I have been missing to add `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` to the project. I wasn't aware that this assembly is necessary because there seems to be *no need* to add it as "using" clause. At least, my code is now compiling by just adding the package with NuGet (but no changes to the using statements). I am a bit confused.

Comment: That's one of the downsides to extensions which Microsoft abuses a little too much in Core, in my opinion. `IServiceCollection.Configure` exists outside of that namespace, but doesn't do what the extension method does. Unless you explicitly include the extension namespace, it's essentially not using the right method, and you get an exception. The problem is that extensions are a bit too magical, and Visual Studio isn't great about cluing you in to the fact that you need to add a using or even which namespace to add.